# How to extract table from an image file and write in a csv file in R

Tags: r

i have a image file that contains table with name, address and phone details. I want to extract the table from this image file in R and write that in a csv file.

I was using the tesseract package to read the image file.

```
library(tesseract)
eng <- tesseract("eng")
text <- tesseract::ocr("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfjym.png", engine = eng)
cat(text)
```

then i was writing it to a text file, however i wanted to write the output in a csv file, but the dataframe is a single column with this function.

[image file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfjym.png)

Comment: Can you supply what function you were using to write to csv? That will help us point you in the right direction. If I'm understanding your question correctly, everything is fine up until that point, but you haven't told us what you've tried so far.

Comment: First you need to address the alignment issue, that the zip codes aren't aligned with their corresponding records.